# "Overwrite"/replace empty/wrong entries in table MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I try the following MySQL query to "overwrite"/replace empty/wrong entries in my table, but it´s not working. I get an error:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'T2.Produktbezeichnung' in 'field list'

Can somebody directly see what´s wrong?

```
UPDATE Bestellung_Bestelldetails AS T1
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT Bestellnummer, 
Artikelnummer, 
Produktkategorie, 
`Hersteller/Marke`, 
MAX(Produktbezeichnung),  
MAX(`Verkaufspreis des Artikels`), 
MAX(`Rabatt auf dem Artikel`), 
MAX(`Einkaufspreis des Artikels`), 
`Bestellte Menge des Artikels`, 
`Bezahlte Menge des Artikels`, 
MAX(`Versandte Menge des Artikels`), 
MAX(`Zurückgesandte Menge des Artikels`), 
`Verkaufsstatus des Artikels`, 
`Shop` 
FROM Bestellung_Bestelldetails GROUP BY Bestellnummer) AS T2 
ON T1.Bestellnummer=T2.Bestellnummer 
SET T1.Produktbezeichnung=T2.Produktbezeichnung,
T1.`Verkaufspreis des Artikels`=T2.`Verkaufspreis des Artikels`, 
T1.`Rabatt auf dem Artikel`=T2.`Rabatt auf dem Artikel`, 
T1.`Einkaufspreis des Artikels`=T2.`Einkaufspreis des Artikels`, 
T1.`Einkaufspreis des Artikels`=T2.`Einkaufspreis des Artikels`, 
T1.`Versandte Menge des Artikels`=T2.`Versandte Menge des Artikels`, 
T1.`Zurückgesandte Menge des Artikels`=T2.`Zurückgesandte Menge des Artikels`
WHERE T1.`Verkaufspreis des Artikels` IS NULL;
```

Thanks for your support!

Comment: Don't see a field `Produktbezeichnung` in the subquery for T2. The `MAX` won't have that field name. Use an alias

Comment: That was the mistake! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the proper alias for the max column

```
  UPDATE Bestellung_Bestelldetails AS T1
  INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT Bestellnummer, 
  Artikelnummer, 
  Produktkategorie, 
  `Hersteller/Marke`, 
  MAX(Produktbezeichnung) AS Produktbezeichnung ,  
  MAX(`Verkaufspreis des Artikels`) AS `Verkaufspreis des Artikels`, 
  MAX(`Rabatt auf dem Artikel`) AS  `Rabatt auf dem Artikel`, 
  MAX(`Einkaufspreis des Artikels`) AS `Einkaufspreis des Artikels` , 
  `Bestellte Menge des Artikels`, 
  `Bezahlte Menge des Artikels`, 
  MAX(`Versandte Menge des Artikels`)  AS `Versandte Menge des Artikels`, 
  MAX(`Zurückgesandte Menge des Artikels`) AS  `Zurückgesandte Menge des Artikels`, 
  `Verkaufsstatus des Artikels`, 
  `Shop` 
  FROM Bestellung_Bestelldetails GROUP BY Bestellnummer) AS T2 
  ON T1.Bestellnummer=T2.Bestellnummer 
  SET T1.Produktbezeichnung=T2.Produktbezeichnung,
  T1.`Verkaufspreis des Artikels`=T2.`Verkaufspreis des Artikels`, 
  T1.`Rabatt auf dem Artikel`=T2.`Rabatt auf dem Artikel`, 
  T1.`Einkaufspreis des Artikels`=T2.`Einkaufspreis des Artikels`, 
  T1.`Einkaufspreis des Artikels`=T2.`Einkaufspreis des Artikels`, 
  T1.`Versandte Menge des Artikels`=T2.`Versandte Menge des Artikels`, 
  T1.`Zurückgesandte Menge des Artikels`=T2.`Zurückgesandte Menge des Artikels`
  WHERE T1.`Verkaufspreis des Artikels` IS NULL;
```